# Can't retrieve value from input field express pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm confused as to why I can't properly retrieve the value I enter into the input field in the `pug` code below. I have similar sections in this file that are written pretty much exactly the same and they work fine but for whatever reason I cannot pull the `title` value from the input field when referencing it from my `express` code.

`index.pug` html code:

```
section(class="get")
h3 Get Data By Title
form(action="/get-data",method="get")
  div(class="input")
    label(for="title") Title
    input(type="text", id="title", name="title")
  button(type="submit") LOAD
div
  if posts
    each val in items
      article(class="item")
        div Title: #{val.title}
        div Content: #{val.content}
        div Author: #{val.author}
        div ID: #{val._id}
```

And the `express` code in my `index.js` file where I try to retrieve the value from `input` with `id="title"` and use it to query my database:

```
router.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("get-data")
  var item = {
    title: req.body.title
  };
  console.log(item);
  // Use mongoose to find data from database
  UserData.find(item)
      .then(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc)
        res.render('index', {title:"Movie Database",items: doc});
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

When I view the console output I can see that I retrieve no value, despite the value I entered appearing in my `get` query url.

```
0|myapp_node  | get-data
0|myapp_node  | { title: undefined }
0|myapp_node  | []
0|myapp_node  | GET /get-data?title=findme 304 54.497 ms - -
0|myapp_node  | GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 0.382 ms - -
```

Below is the entire rendered HTML from pug for my file. It includes extra information that may or may not be relevant:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Movie Database</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Movie Database</h1>
        <p>Welcome to Movie Database</p>
        <section class="insert">
            <h3>Insert Data</h3>
            <form action="/insert" method="post">
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <input type="text" id="content" name="content">
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="author">Author</label>
                    <input type="text" id="author" name="author">
                </div>
                <button type="submit">INSERT</button>
            </form>
        </section>
        <section class="get">
            <h3>Get Data By Title</h3>
            <form action="/get-data" method="get">
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
                </div>
                <button type="submit">LOAD</button>
            </form>
            <div></div>
        </section>
        <section class="update">
            <h3>Update Data</h3>
            <form action="/update" method="post">
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="id">ID</label>
                    <input type="text" id="id" name="id">
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <input type="text" id="content" name="content">
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <label for="author">Author</label>
                    <input type="text" id="author" name="author">
                </div>
                <button type="submit">UPDATE</button>
            </form>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my `app.js` file:

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
// var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
// app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant layout of the rendered html and that network request that is send when you click LOAD?

Comment: @Austio I added the rendered HTML to the bottom of the post. The network request is sent when I click the LOAD button is what I've included just above the code snippet, unless you're talking about something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the data you're looking for is on the query property of your request object. The way that you know this is that, in your server log, you see:

```
GET /get-data?title=findme
```

When you see a ? following the path, there's a query coming through on the request object. To access those properties, you just tap into req.query.title or req.query.you_prop_name_here.

Here's a snippet from the express docs to show you how this works a bit more.

```
// GET /search?q=tobi+ferret
req.query.q
// => "tobi ferret"

// GET /shoes?order=desc&shoe[color]=blue&shoe[type]=converse
req.query.order
// => "desc"

req.query.shoe.color
// => "blue"

req.query.shoe.type
// => "converse"
```

Comment: Good suggestion. It appears I didn't have `body-parser` installed. However, installing it hasn't fixed my issue.

Comment: Check out my example above to make sure you're using it correctly. Requires some additional fiddling around with.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I added the `bodyParser` to my `app.js` file as you showed but I'm still not able to retrieve the value from the input field.

Comment: What is the full path where this form is located, and what is the full path to that route up until "/get-data"?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. The form is located on my homepage html and the /get-data route is right off of that (so hostname/get-route). I'm really new to webdev so I'm sorry if this isn't what you asked for.

Comment: That's okay! What would really help is if you could show us your app.js file. That should get us to the bottom of this.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I've uploaded another snippet that contains my `app.js` file.

Comment: Okay so it looks like this request is coming in on req.query. So what you actually want here is not the body but the query string that's coming in. So as opposed to doing req.body.title, do req.query.title. That should do the trick.

Comment: That worked! Would you mind sharing with me how you knew that was the case?

Comment: I initially thought your router might have been wired up to a path that extended the root, but then I took another look at your log and noticed the problem. Just modified my answer at the top so others can see as well! If you could upvote, that would be greatly appreciated :)